# Merge changes Pandas types

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm using Python 3 (don't know if the info is relevant).
I have 2 Pandas DataFrames (coming from `read_csv()`): `Compact` and `SDSS_DR7_to_DR8`. Before merge, they contain types as follow :

```
Compact.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2070 entries, 0 to 2069
Data columns (total 8 columns):
Group    2070 non-null int64
Id       2070 non-null int64
RA       2070 non-null float64
Dec      2070 non-null float64
z        2070 non-null float64
R        2070 non-null float64
G        2070 non-null float64
objid    2070 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(5), int64(3)
memory usage: 129.5 KB
```

And

```
SDSS_DR7_to_DR8.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 243500 entries, 0 to 243499
Data columns (total 5 columns):
specobjid    243500 non-null int64
dr8objid     243500 non-null int64
dr7objid     243500 non-null int64
ra           243500 non-null float64
dec          243500 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(3)
memory usage: 9.3 MB
```

I perform a `Compact=pd.merge(Compact, SDSS_DR7_to_DR8, left_on=['objid'], right_on=['dr8objid'], how='left')`. It is executed without error, but the result is a mess. When I check the types in the new DataFrame, I get this:

```
Compact.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2070 entries, 0 to 2069
Data columns (total 13 columns):
Group        2070 non-null int64
Id           2070 non-null int64
RA           2070 non-null float64
Dec          2070 non-null float64
z            2070 non-null float64
R            2070 non-null float64
G            2070 non-null float64
objid        2070 non-null int64
specobjid    1275 non-null float64
dr8objid     1275 non-null float64
dr7objid     1275 non-null float64
ra           1275 non-null float64
dec          1275 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(10), int64(3)
memory usage: 226.4 KB
```

So during the merge, `dr8objid` (and some others) has (have) been cast to `float64`. How is it possible, and what can I do to prevent this (hoping this is the origin of the mess in the merge)?

EDIT
So, to be more specific: if I create `df`

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[[1000000000000000000,1]], columns=['key','data'])
```

`key` and `data` are both `int64`. I create a transcoding df:

```
trans=pd.DataFrame(data=[[1000000000000000000,2000000000000000000]], 
                   columns=['key','key2'])
```

which 2 keys are `int64`. Then

```
df2 = pd.merge(df, trans, on=['key'], how='left')
```

Gives a nice result, and `key`, `key2` and `data` are still `int64`.

Nevertheless, if I define

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[[1000000000000000000,1],[1000000000000000001,2]],
                columns=['key','data'])
```

Now after the merge, I get
[image]

and now `key2` has switched to a `float64`. How to prevent this? Is it because `NaN` must be connected with a float ? If so, is it possible to set the merge to define the result of merging to 0 or -1 if there is no correspondance, keeping the whole column to `int64`?

Comment: The output type will be the same as ‘left’. Said the docs

Comment: I must had that when I switch from `how='left'` to `how='right'` (which gives me far too many lines than needed, but I could filter them), `dr8objid` stays `int64`, but other fields (like `Group` and `Id`) now become `float64`.

Comment: Thank you @bakka . Nevertheless, in this case, left `objid` and right `dr8objid` are both `int64`...

Comment: Addentum to my comment on right merge: my key `objid` becomes a `float64`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Update:*** in Pandas 0.24, there now are [Nullable integer data types](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html).

As of this writing, the Pandas does not seem choose the nullable int data type for the result of the merge. But it's possible to convert both arrays to the nullable int type `Int64` before the merge.

Consider

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[[1000000000000000000,1],[1000000000000000001,2]],
                columns=['key','data']).astype("Int64")
trans=pd.DataFrame(data=[[1000000000000000000,2000000000000000000]], 
                   columns=['key','key2']).astype("Int64")
df2 = pd.merge(df, trans, on=['key'], how='left')
```

Result:

```
>>> df2
                   key  data                 key2
0  1000000000000000000     1  2000000000000000000
1  1000000000000000001     2                 <NA>

>>> df2.dtypes
key     Int64
data    Int64
key2    Int64
dtype: object
```

---

**Original answer**, for Pandas < v0.24:

> Is it because NaN must be connected with a float ?

Correct. There is no NaN value in an int, so missing values can only be represented in floats.

You could either filter your data before merging, making sure that there are no NaNs created.

Or you could fill in the NaNs with a value of your choosing after the merge, and then restore the dtype.

Comment: The more I use pandas, the more I don't like its kind of logics. Is there any good reason to allow NaN for float but not for int?

Comment: @CesareIurlaro NaNs are usually only defined for floating point values, and not at all available for fixed-size integers, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN. Or just try `int(float('nan'))` in Python, it throws `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`. So it was not a Pandas design decision, but how Python (and any common programming language really) works. Interestingly enough, Pandas has since added a new experimental data dtype just to solve this issue, see my edit to the answer!

Comment: Still the automatic cast of an int column to float doesn't make sense to me. But it is a nice thing they added the nullable int data type.